# authenticating on every request

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, web-applications, https

Is there a practical reason that it is bad to authenticate a user on every single http request? Lets say i have a single page web app and I use https post for every ajax request (well, every one that is requesting information specific to a user anyway), and include the username and password.

Now, before I get asked - the reason is I'd like to keep the web server stateless. I can't actually think of a specific problem here except that the password is being sent over the network more times than it would otherwise. All else equal, I'd prefer to send it as few times as possible but I can't see how the risk is very high at all to sending it multiple times.

Is there something very obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think transporting the credentials over SSL multiple times is a problem but how are you going to store the credentials so you can pass in each request? Unless you are going to ask the user for their username and password each time you'll end up saving the sensitive information in the browser.

Is there a reason you don't want to use a cookie to persist the authentication? The web server would still remain stateless. Or you could use a token system like OAuth 2.0

Comment: I'm just saving the username and password as variables in the javascript. The user needs to sign in each time they actually use the web app, but if they sign out or navigate away from the page, the application state is lost. But since its a single page application, moving around the application simply means making ajax requests and loading a different template - ie state isn't lost.